# Add local binstubs to rbenv (getting command not found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zsh, rbenv

If you have simple shell command binstubs in the local `bin` directory of a Rails project (e.g. not generated by or running a gem), rbenv seems to have trouble executing them. For example, @tpope's [heroku binstubs](https://github.com/tpope/heroku-binstubs) generate a binstub named `production` in the local bin directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
HEROKU_APP=myapp-production HKAPP=myapp-production exec "${HEROKU_COMMAND:-heroku}" "$@"
```

After an rbenv rehash, the production command shows up in the `~/.rbenv/shims` directory looking something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
[ -n "$RBENV_DEBUG" ] && set -x

program="${0##*/}"
if [ "$program" = "ruby" ]; then
  for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
    -e* | -- ) break ;;
    */* )
      if [ -f "$arg" ]; then
        export RBENV_DIR="${arg%/*}"
        break
      fi
      ;;
    esac
  done
fi

export RBENV_ROOT="/Users/Username/.rbenv"
exec "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv" exec "$program" "$@"
```

So executing `which production` gives you:

```
/Users/Username/.rbenv/shims/production
```

But executing `rbenv which production` (or trying to run the command) gives you:

```
rbenv: production: command not found
```

I'm new to rbenv so maybe I missed a config step?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently project-specific binstubs in Rails projects should be kept outside of the local `bin/` directory since those are primarily for [application scripts](https://github.com/ianheggie/rbenv-binstubs#installation). So one approach (i.e. that used by the [rbenv-binstubs](https://github.com/ianheggie/rbenv-binstubs) plugin) is to keep local binstubs separate and override rbenv shims with that local binstub directory (e.g. `.bundle/bin`). So by using the plugin you might see this result from `which production`:

```
/Users/Username/.rbenv/shims/production
```

But if you move the `production` binstub to `.bundle/bin`, then `rbenv which production` should yield:

```
{PROJECT_ROOT}/.bundle/bin/production
```

Comment: The notion that the local `bin` directory should only be used for _application script_ is a farce. With the latest versions of rbenv, rbenv-binstubs plugin is no longer necessary, and rbenv even has a wiki document about how locally installed binstubs can be used. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs

Comment: @RyanMcGeary what an oddly heated and unhelpful comment. If you have a correction/update to the answer, especially if it is based on new versions of these tools, submit an edit or add a new answer and I'll correct. If the question itself is bad given my (stated) limited understanding at the time, perhaps it makes sense to remove it altogether.